# Is this a Combination problem?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, permutations

In how many ways can the letters of the word ADRIENNE be arranged so that no two vowels are together? Simplify your answer.

My answer is the following:

$\dfrac{8!}{2!2!} - \dfrac{4!}{2!} \cdot \large  ^5C_4 \cdot \dfrac{4!}{2!} = 9,360$ . But my instructor's answer is $720$. Why?

Comment: Now I am not sure what you have done at all, or why you have done it. You seem to be trying to exclude the combinations with two vowels occurring together, but you have not explained how you have identified the combinations you are intending to exclude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are five possible setup. You can have one of
$$
VCVCVCVC\\
CVCVCVCV\\
VCCVCVCV\\
VCVCCVCV\\
VCVCVCCV\\
$$
Each of them have $\frac{4!}{2!}\frac{4!}{2!}$ ways of occuring, making it $120$ per setup. Five of them makes $720$.

Answer (score 1):

There are four vowels and four consonants.

First locate the consonants with potential spaces for the vowels: $$*C*C*C*C*$$

Now there are five places for the vowels, and each place can take at most one vowel. So we choose four places, and then an order for the four vowels, and then take into account the two $E$s to give $\binom 54 \cdot 4! \cdot \frac 1{2!}=60$

The consonants can be placed in $\frac {4!}{2!}$ ways, taking into account the two $N$s - and this is $12$ ways.

$60 \cdot 12 = 720$

Answer (score 1):

There are $4$ vowels, AEEI, and $4$ consonants, DNNR. You must put at least one consonant between any two adjacent vowels. Using $C$ to represent any consonant, we have a skeleton $_C_C_C_C_$ with $5$ open slots, and we can put the $4$ vowels into those slots in any way that does **not** put two of them into the same slot.

- First count the consonant skeletons: there are $\dfrac{4!}{2!}=\dfrac{24}2=12$ distinguishable permutations of DNNR, since the two N’s are indistinguishable.
- Now we have to choose $4$ of the $5$ slots for the $4$ vowels: there are $\dbinom54=5$ ways to do this.
- Finally, we have to arrange the $4$ vowels in the $4$ chosen slots. This is exactly like the first step, so it can be done in $\dfrac{4!}{2!}=12$ ways.

Thus, there are $12\cdot5\cdot12=720$ distinguishable permutations of the letters of ADRIENNE in which no two vowels are adjacent.

Your calculation begins by counting all of the distinguishable permutations of ADRIENNE. From this you subtract $$\frac{4!}{2!}\cdot\binom54\cdot\frac{4!}{2!}\;,$$ which is actually the number that you were looking for. Thus, you counted the number of distinguishable permutations of ADRIENNE that **do** have two adjacent vowels.

Comment: @user36829: You’re welcome.